# npm install from git url missing some files

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I try to install the a repo called ng2-tree. When I used 'npm install ng2-tree' command, it will download all the files in src folder,

but when I change to use git url to install, like 'npm install git+https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree.git', it will miss some files in src folder,

the git repo url is https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree/tree. so why, and how can to download all files by git url?

Comment: It probably is not using the same branch as the default branch set in git as is on npm repo.
You can clone the files and then install it manually on your own system.